# Connection Refused and Cannot connect to Controller Error

Tags: jboss, keycloak, kie

I am getting an error when i try to stop services

```
  Failed to connect to the controller: The controller is not available at localhost:9990: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://localhost:9990. The connection failed: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to http-remoting://localhost:9990. The connection failed: Connection refused
```

when i try to start services, i get below error and need to restart the server multiple times to resolve it. need a solution to avoid errors during start and stop services. we use keycloack sercurity as well

```
2020-02-11 19:21:01,191 WARNING [com.lgc.dsl.admin.security.controllers.DSSecurity] (default task-12) Connect to localhost:8880 [localhost/IP] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2020-02-11 19:21:09,462 WARN  [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http:localhost:port/dsbpm-console/rest/controller/server/dsbpm-kieserver error Error while sending PUT request to localhost:port/dsbpm-console/rest/controller/server/dsbpm-kieserver response code 405
```

Answer (score 0):

Default kie server is not showing up in the server section

```
2020-02-11 19:21:01,191 WARNING [com.lgc.dsl.admin.security.controllers.DSSecurity] (default task-12) Connect to localhost:8880 [localhost/IP] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2020-02-11 19:21:09,462 WARN  [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http:localhost:port/dsbpm-console/rest/controller/server/dsbpm-kieserver error Error while sending PUT request to localhost:port/dsbpm-console/rest/controller/server/dsbpm-kieserver response code 405
```

Check if you have 'dsbpm-console' for 'org.kie.server.controller' property, like as:

Comment: the complete resolution is missing, it ends at like as an no config details available.